# How to check loadrunner transaction status using java over http?

Tags: java, loadrunner

How to check loadrunner transaction status using java over http? For Web -HTTP/HTML protocol there is lr_get_transaction_status("transaction_name") function. But I cannot find anything like it for java over http.

Comment: if it exists, it will be lr.get_transaction_status()

Comment: https://admhelp.microfocus.com/vugen/en/2020_SP2-SP3/help/function_reference/Content/FuncRef/java_vuser/etc/lrFuncRef_JV_Alphabtcl_Lstng_Funcs.htm

Comment: unfortunately, there is no lr.get_transaction_status function in loadrunner.

Comment: Then check your own status, Create your own variable to track it.  Then check your own variable in the absence of a built in function.   You might consider leveraging built in constants for pass and fail

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to below

```
lr.start_transaction("Get_Status");
...
if (r.status("200") != -1 || r.status("201") != -1){
}
    lr.end_transaction("Get_Status", lr.PASS);
}else{
    lr.end_transaction("Get_Status", lr.FAIL);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [lr.get_transaction_status](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/vugen/en/2021/help/function_reference/Content/FuncRef/c_vuser/examples/lrFuncRef_CV_lr_gt_trnsstts_Example.htm).